# How to put a Selenium Webdriver browser into a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, user-interface, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

This is possible, put a Selenium driver Windows inside a GUI?, I have to make a GUI, for a client, normally I send this request for a heroku and I run this in heroku, but my client say  "NO".

I make this request using Selenium and Tkinder, and work perfect, so now I want put this driver inside the GUI, this is possible?, thanks fellas :)

Comment: Your use of terminology is a bit unclear. The selenium driver is not a GUI component so I don't know what you mean by adding it to a GUI. Are you asking how to embed a web browser in a tkinter window?

Comment: Yes!, is possible?

Comment: There are several similar questions on this site. Have you read them and their answers?

Comment: After i create this question I search for this, the parameter in my search don't return this answers can you give me a link about this?

Comment: [\[tkinter\] browser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+browser)